# Is it possible to find the area under a curve with an infinite number of holes (removable discontinuities)?

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, improper-integrals

After learning about improper integrals, we discussed about the idea that a hole (removable discontinuity) has no effect on the area under a curve since it is just a single point and therefore has no width and it is pretty fascinating.

However, I then have to ask, what if there were an infinite number of holes along the function (for example, there is a hole every multiple of 5 or something) could you still find an area? As a side question to that, what if the whole function consisted of holes (is that even possible?) and if so could you find the area under it?

Comment: What is integrable depends on your definition of integration.  If you take the function which is 1 for rational values and 0 for irrational values (and which has a hole everywhere), it is not integrable according to Riemann integration, but it is Lebesgue integrable.

Comment: Would the Lebesgue integral of the function which is $1$ for *ir*rational values and $0$ for rationals from $0$ to $1$ be $1$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner: Over the interval $[0,1]$, yes it would.